# My app won't run on LG G5. USB debugging & OEM driver are OK

Tags: android, lg

I'm struggling to get my stock standard Android application ("hello world") running on my LG G5. My device is just not picked up by Android studio's deployment target window ("No USB devices or running emulators detected").

Can not understand why though because I do not pick up any usb driver issues in computer manager (G5 SE identified under portable devices without shown driver problem), and my phone's development option with USB debugging is enabled as shown by Android [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html?utm_source=android-studio).

Some additional guidance would help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all run **adb devices** (located in android sdk>platform-tools>) from command line / terminal and check if your phone is listed.

If not restart adb :

**adb kill-server**

**adb start-server**

If it doesn't work try changing **USB Configuration** on your phone: select MTP or PTP. You can change this from top panel when your phone is connected.

If this will show confirmation dialog with MAC address confirm it.

Your phone has to be visible by ADB before it can be visible by Android Studio.

Comment: Hey Maciej, thanks for the suggestion. You were on the right track with USB configuration. After re-selecting that my USB driver reconfigured as a unknown ADB device (seen from computer management screen). After downloading the LG driver again (LGMobileDriver_WHQL_Ver_xxx.exe) everything worked and device picked up from AStudio. Thank you.